# Why won't basic UIScrollView with a few buttons scroll?

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, uiscrollview

Why won't basic UIScrollView with a few buttons scroll?

So all I have done is:

- Create a view based iPhone app
- drag in a UIScrollView into the main controller xib file
- the scrollview now sits as a child of View in IB
- in IB in scrollview increase it's view height up to 1000
- add some buttons to the scroll view (so they appear as children of the scroll view)
- did create the instance variable also, and property IBOutlet, synthesize
- linked in IB the File Owner scrollView outlet to the scroll view
- checked to ensure the scroll view in IB had the attribute "scrolling enabled" ticked

But still after all this in the iPhone simulator it won't let me scroll the view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one more thing you have to do: set the `contentSize` property on your scroll view to an appropriate value:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(
   scrollView.bounds.size.width,
   CGRectGetMaxY(bottommostSubview.frame)
)];
```

Where `bottommostSubview` is an outlet connected to the subview of the scrollview that’s closest to the bottom. You could also write a method to find this view automatically, or just hard-code a value if you know the size will never change.

The default `contentSize` is `CGSizeZero` which effectively disables scrolling.

Comment: thanks Todd - I tried throwing in "[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(400, 1000)];", and whilst this let me see some scrolling of the view left-right, there was still no way to scroll up/down?  Any ideas here?

Comment: As ryyst said, make sure your scrollview’s frame is not 1000 points tall — it should be the normal 460, the default in IB.

Comment: actually I just went back and changed the scrollView view height back to 480 from 1000 in IB and now the up/down scrolling seems to work!  Not exactly sure why this fixed it....

Comment: That’s because the frame of the scrollview is only what determines the region the content will be drawn inside of, not the area that will be scrolled. Think of the scrollview’s frame as the size of a window looking onto the actual content (the size of which is determined by `contentSize`). Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't want to change your scrollviews `frame.size.height` property to 1000.0, but your scrollviews `contentSize.height`.

Comment: oh - this parameter isn't available in IB then?  do you need to do this programmatically?

Comment: @Greg: I believe `UIScrollView` determines its content size automatically (I suppose it sets the content size when you add or remove subviews from it). If there's no parameter in IB, set it programmatically, it shouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

**No, the correct answer is:**

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1700)];  
}
```

The original answer I founded on next link:

[UIScrollView won't scroll (Storyboards) -> Find Evana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458073/uiscrollview-wont-scroll-storyboards?rq=1)

I waste a lot of time trying implement scroll (and repeatedly). I have even used 2 views (UIScrollView and UIView inside the first)

It is not necessary!

THE KEY IS: **viewDidLayoutSubviews**

In the storyboard you implement UIScrollView as any other element,

but the key is **setContentSize** in method **viewDidLayoutSubviews**